# index UITableView not loading an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am showing the data in index Table as shown in picture, For thumbnail image i am fetching from photos array by the index path of the sorted array. I am getting the photo name properly but it is not loading into the TableViewCell

```
 NSString *sectionTitle = [IndexTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  NSArray *sectionAnimals = [dictionaryIndex objectForKey:sectionTitle];
  NSString *cellText = [sectionAnimals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.name.text=cellText;

  NSUInteger indexofTheObject=[sortedLastName indexOfObject:cellText];
  NSString *photoString=[arrPhoto objectAtIndex:indexofTheObject];

  NSLog(@"photo %@",photoString);
  cell.imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:photoString];
```

[image: index Table]

Comment: show your code friend

Comment: i already shown buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
NSString *sectionTitle = [IndexTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *sectionAnimals = [dictionaryIndex objectForKey:sectionTitle];
cell.name.text = [sectionAnimals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[arrPhoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the images to Images.xcassets ?

If not, and you're loading images direct from file, then you should use (in Swift - sorry!):

```
var boundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()

cell.imgView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: boundle.pathForResource("image", ofType: "png")!)
```